# Eagle I can not change the isolete value of bottom Ground polygon

Tags: pcb, ground, eaglecad, isolated, polygon

well this is my PCB design with Eagle Autodesk. Ground polygon looks perfect with Isolate value 0.8128 [mm] on Top.

[image]

but this value can not effect bottom polygon Why? How can apply 0.8128 isolate value to bottom ground polygon.

[image]

Comment: Do you by any chance have multiple copies of the polygon on the bottom layer by mistake? That's the only reason I can think of why the setting wouldn't take effect.

Comment: well I have sellect all PCB than I found GND polygon and than I see bottom is 0 isolate value. this why i didnt know. but after change the value instead 0 to 0.8128 everything become normal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change both planes individually. And using 0 as insulation value will make Eagle use the value provided in the DRC. So you could just set them both to 0 and change them in one go with the DRC